# jQuery loading issue

Tags: jquery, wordpress, load

I'm developing a WordPress site at http://fremont.alchemycs.com and I keep running into jQuery problems.  There are two features on the page that use jQuery - a slideshow at the top of the page, and an accordion menu in the sidebar.  For some reason, I can't get them both to work at once.  I get "not a function" errors for one or the other, depending on where I load jQuery.

Here is my header as it stands at the moment:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
<title>Fremont, Seattle</title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://fremont.alchemycs.com/wp-content/themes/center/style.css" />
<link rel="pingback" href="http://fremont.alchemycs.com/xmlrpc.php" />
<!--
<script src="http://fremont.alchemycs.com/wp-content/themes/center/js/modernizr-1.6.min.js"></script>
-->
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Fremont, Seattle &raquo; Feed" href="http://fremont.alchemycs.com/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Fremont, Seattle &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://fremont.alchemycs.com/comments/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Fremont, Seattle &raquo; Home Comments Feed" href="http://fremont.alchemycs.com/home/feed/" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='ccf_custom-css'  href='http://fremont.alchemycs.com/wp-content/plugins/constant-contact-form/class/ccf_custom.css?ver=3.2.1' type='text/css' media='screen' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='contact-form-7-css'  href='http://fremont.alchemycs.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/styles.css?ver=3.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='amr-ical-events-list-css'  href='http://fremont.alchemycs.com/wp-content/plugins/amr-ical-events-list/css/icallist.css?ver=1' type='text/css' media='all' />

<link rel='stylesheet' id='amr-ical-events-list_print-css'  href='http://fremont.alchemycs.com/wp-content/plugins/amr-ical-events-list/css/icalprint.css?ver=1' type='text/css' media='print' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://fremont.alchemycs.com/wp-includes/js/l10n.js?ver=20101110'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://fremont.alchemycs.com/wp-content/plugins/constant-contact-form/class/ccf_ajax.js?ver=3.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://fremont.alchemycs.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.6.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://fremont.alchemycs.com/wp-content/plugins/jquery-vertical-accordion-menu/js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js?ver=3.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://fremont.alchemycs.com/wp-content/plugins/jquery-vertical-accordion-menu/js/jquery.cookie.js?ver=3.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://fremont.alchemycs.com/wp-content/plugins/jquery-vertical-accordion-menu/js/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.9.js?ver=3.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://fremont.alchemycs.com/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.js?ver=20090102'></script>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://fremont.alchemycs.com/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://fremont.alchemycs.com/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 

<link rel='index' title='Fremont, Seattle' href='http://fremont.alchemycs.com/' />
<link rel='next' title='Calendar' href='http://fremont.alchemycs.com/events/' />
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.2.1" />

<!-- All in One SEO Pack 1.6.13.8 by Michael Torbert of Semper Fi Web Designob_start_detected [-1,-1] -->
<meta name="description" content="The Center of the Universe" />
<link rel="canonical" href="http://fremont.alchemycs.com/" />
<!-- /all in one seo pack -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fremont.alchemycs.com/wp-content/plugins/social-media-widget/social_widget.css" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wop-css'  href='http://fremont.alchemycs.com/wp-content/plugins/widgets-on-pages/wop.css' type='text/css' media='all' /><!-- BEGIN Hackadelic Sliding Notes 1.6.5 -->
<style type="text/css">
.concealed { display: none }
.block { display: block }
</style>
<!-- END Hackadelic Sliding Notes 1.6.5 -->

    <script src="http://fremont.alchemycs.com/wp-content/themes/center/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://fremont.alchemycs.com/wp-content/themes/center/css/flexslider.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      $(window).load(function() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider();
      });
    </script>

</head>
```

When the above is my header, I get an error message: $ is not a function

But if I change the header to load jQuery later in the header, I get similar errors about the accordion menu function.

This is probably something simple, but I'm having trouble figuring it out.

Thanks!

EDIT - Let me emphasize that I have experimented with where I load jQuery, and even if I do it way up at the top of the header so it is the very first thing, only one script works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you load the jQuery core first.
Which means that this line

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://fremont.alchemycs.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.6.1'></script>
```

Should be the first script tag.

Comment: Right now, jQuery is where it is because a plugin put it there.  But to try to get this to work, I removed the plugin's jQuery call, and I put jQuery right up at the top of the header.  I still had the same problem - only one of the jQuery functions on the page worked.

Comment: As Tuncay Demirtepe stated, jQuery instead of $ works, for some reason your version of jQuery is not correct, when I include http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js' to your page everything is fine. You should either use jQuery(window).... or overwrite the file with a correct version

Comment: Your files were indeed in the right order, the files before the jQuery core have nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: Nope, that still doesn't do it - I put http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js way up at the top of the header, and now the slideshow works but the accordion menu doesn't.  This is what has been happening to me all along - I can get one or the other to work, but not both.

Comment: And for what it's worth, using jQuery(window) didn't make any difference at all.

Comment: I am currently on your site, and it seems that jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.9.js is **not** included on your site.

Comment: Okay, so I removed the plugin that stopped plugins from loading jQuery, and now the accordion works, but the slideshow doesn't.  Maybe I just need to use a different slideshow, because it looks like this slideshow doesn't want to play nicely with the accordion, but I would really like to use it because it has some really nice features.

Comment: That plugin definitely doesn't want to cooperate

Comment: to make your slideshow work with your accordion use the jQuery from the accordion and use this code for your slideshow `jQuery(window).load(function() {
     jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider();
   });` that is the only fix I can think of and I don't get any errors.

Comment: you're almost there! replace `$('.flexslider').flexslider();` with `jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider();`

Comment: Yay, that did it!!  Thank you!  I'm really glad I can actually use these two scripts together.

Answer (score 0):

you should include the `jquery.js` first and then the rest of plugin `js` files that uses the `jQuery`, order does matter, and wrap the jQuery code inside the ready handler

```
$(function(){
 //
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add the jquery code reference **above any other plugin**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://fremont.alchemycs.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.6.1'></script>
```

**Instead** you can use google lib reference to the latest jquery version(1.7.1)

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

It should enhance the download time to your users(It should be the first script tag either.).

Comment: As I said to Qurben, I did this - I put jQuery way up at the top of the page, and still only one of the jQuery functions on the page worked.  There must be something else going on here.